# Position text that appears when having the cursor over an image?

Tags: css, position

I have managed to get a text showing when having the cursor over an image, but now I want to position it so that it appears on the image, preferrably in the center of it. And I would also like to change the font size of it. As I am new to web development I am not sure how to arrange this.

JSFiddle with necessary info: http://jsfiddle.net/gGvb2/

HTML:

```
<article class="art-1">  <img src="nutrition.jpg">
<span>Nutrition</span></article>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
img {
    width: 462px;
}
img:hover ~ span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest relatively positioning the parent `article` element, and then absolutely positioning the `span` element relative to it. I'm not sure where you want the `span` to appear, but in this example it has a width of `100%` and has `text-align:center` for horizontal centering.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/se5E4/)

```
span {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover ~ span, span:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
article {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
article span {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px; left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background:white;
}
```